# Installing create-react-app on Huawei tablet and getting this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, huawei-developers, termux

[Termux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TQoP.jpg)

I am trying to create react app on Huawei tablet which running harmony os but after installing nodejs I am getting this error

Comment: convert  image to text and make it accessible for index engine